# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined Unit Test AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-mocha, gulp-karma

I am stuck to do the Unit Test with Karma, I don't have idea how to the unit test because it's my first time. I am using AngularJS and the unit test is Karma.

The thing is this: I'm using a service to obtain the firstName, lastName and PhoneNumber of the customer to show in my form, and it works without any problem BUT, when I'm trying to do the unit test the error is always this:

```
directionFormulation component should load customer profile FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

directionFormulation.js

```
  function directionFormulationController(event, customer, resolveLocation, order) {
    this.$onInit = onInit;
    this.input = this.input || {};

    function onInit() {
      loadCustomerData();
    }

    function loadCustomerData() {
      this.input.firstName = order.customer.firstName;
      this.input.lastName = order.customer.lastName;
      this.input.phoneNumber = order.customer.phoneNumber;

    }
  }
})();
```

Unit test: directionFormulation.spec.js:

```
  it('should load customer data', function () {
    var emptyFirstName = { firstName: 'something'};

    component.$onInit();
    order.customer.firstName = { firstName: 'Something'};
    order.customer.lastName = { lastName: 'Something' };
    order.customer.phoneNumber = { phoneNumber: 55555555};
    // component.input = {
    //   firstName: 'something',
    //   lastName: 'something',
    //   phoneNumber: 55555555
    // };

    component.loadCustomerData();
    $rootScope.$apply();
    component.input.firstName = newFirstName;

    expect(component.input.firstName).to.be.equal({firstName: 'something'});
    expect(component.input.lastName).to.be.not.empty;
    expect(component.input.phoneNumber).to.be.null;

  });
});
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, but I will take in advance for the future questions, sorry :(

Comment: @AnubisVolga why did you change your code 2 times ? It has been rollback already one time because it's out of context with the aswer of mcranston18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting `order` into your controller, so you will need to "mock" out `order` for your unit test:

```
describe('addressForm component', function () {
  var component;
  var scope;
  var order;

  beforeEach(function () {
    bard.appModule('shopping.address');
    bard.inject('$rootScope', '$componentController', '$q', 'resolveLocation', 'customer', 'event','order');
    order = {
      customer: {
        firstName: 'Joe',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        phoneNumber: '416-555-1234'
      }
    };
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    component = $componentController('addressForm', { 
      $scope: scope,
      order: order
    });
  });

  it('should be attached to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.addressForm).to.be.equal(component);
  });

  it('should load customer profile', function () {
    component.$onInit();
    component.loadCustomerProfile();

    expect(component.input.firstName).to.be.equal(order.customer.firstName);
    expect(component.input.lastName).to.be.equal(order.customer.lastName);
    expect(component.input.phoneNumber).to.be.equal(order.customer.phoneNumber);
  });
});
```

I'd like to highlight a few other issues:

1. Your first test asserting `expect(scope.addressForm).to.be.equal(component);` is not going to pass. `AddressFormController` is the name of your controller, and a controller is a property on a component.
2. I'm not sure what `bard` refers to in your test and not sure whether `appModule` is a property on your bard instance. Here is a sample of a component test set up of mine: https://gist.github.com/mcranston18/0ded29eca9a53efeb945736b0a053061
3. I would recommend this resource to learn a bit more about testing component controllers: http://www.codelord.net/2017/01/09/unit-testing-angular-components-with-%24componentcontroller/